# How to stop all ajax process in the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, request

How to stop all ajax process in the page using jQuery ?

Comment: @enthusiastic : I want to stop all ajax in page not one of them

Answer (score 1):

The way to kill a single AJAX process is this way

```
var x = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
x.abort()
```

After you declare 'x' and initialize the ajax, simply add `x` to an array. Then you can cycle through the array and call each items `.abort()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the reference and fire

```
ajaxid.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for a process as follows.
event.stopPropagation();